# Websearch for multiple phrases within multiple websites?

Tags: web

Say you had a list of 20 websites and you wanted to search all of those complete sites for 10 different phrases or words at once, and you wanted the results of the search to be shown in an easy to read format that connects the amount of hits connecting a phrase/word to each of the websites. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a search engine and then narrow results to your specified domains. This is an example I tested on Google

> law site: congress.gov OR whitehouse.gov